Is this LTSpice simulation of arduino's command for relay corrrect?
Here is a LTspice simulation for based on the video  Design Relay module PCB using Altium designer

To me, it seems ok, but i am lacking of experiences.
What is your opinion on this LTSpice simulation ? Is there a way to improve it simply.
